# Unable to get XSLT output with custom namespace

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Here is the format of my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns="http://www.example.com/xyz" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <child>
                <element1>xyz</element1>
                <element2>def</element2>
        </child>
</Root>
```

Here is my xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns="http://www.example.com/xyz"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="Root/child">
            <xsl:value-of select="element1"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This does not have any output

When I take the url out of the XML file, I get the output without any problems. However, I would like to get this to work with the namespace working correctly.

I tried a few adjustments based on other questions that I found online:
1) changing the `match="/"` to `"match=Root"` - This just printed out the entire file with no tags

2) changing the `xmlns="http://www.example.com/xyz"` to `xmlns:Root="http://www.example.com/xyz"` - this still didn't print anything out.

I have read a few other similar questions, but the formatting was different enough that it didn't work with my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to qualify every element within your custom namespace also with the namespace prefix within your xslt, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:aa="http://www.example.com/xyz"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="aa:Root/aa:child">
            <xsl:value-of select="aa:element1"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The namespace prefix here is 'aa'.

You create the association between namespace and prefix here

```
xmlns:aa="http://www.example.com/xyz"
```

and you have to use the same prefix 'aa' to refer to the elements 'Root', 'child', 'element1' and 'element2'

like here

```
<xsl:for-each select="aa:Root/aa:child">
    <xsl:value-of select="aa:element1"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

You can also choose a different prefix, 'aa' is just an example.

'Root' also is inside the namespace, because the namespace definition in the source xml document already includes the element where the namespace is introduced:

```
<Root xmlns="http://www.example.com/xyz"> ... </Root>
```

In your souce document xml you haven't assigned a namespace prefix. If you want to a assign prefix there also, it would look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bb:Root xmlns:bb="http://www.example.com/xyz" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <bb:child>
                <bb:element1>xyz</bb:element1>
                <bb:element2>def</bb:element2>
        </bb:child>
</bb:Root>
```

The prefix here is 'bb'. As you see the prefix need not match the prefix in the stylesheet.

Comment: So the namespace prefix does not have to be the same as the namespace definition in the xml document? I can have `Root xmlns="example.com"` in the xml, and `xmlns:whatever="example.com"` in the xslt document? ---just wanted to confirm that this is what you're saying

Comment: And a second follow up question - my xml document is actually a lot more nested than this, and I'm working in a nested loop. In the nested loop, I have a line like this: `<xsl:value-of select="../../root_ID"/>`. When I specify every element with the namespace prefix, how do I specify this line?

Comment: Yes, but "Root" is not the namespace prefix in your source document xml. In your source document you even haven't specified a prefix. This would look like:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bb:Root xmlns:bb="http://www.example.com/xyz" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <bb:child>
                <bb:element1>xyz</bb:element1>
                <bb:element2>def</bb:element2>
        </bb:child>
</bb:Root>`

Comment: I'm getting the file from a third party, and would prefer not to edit it if possible. Is it ok to leave the namespace out of the source xml document?

Comment: Yes, you don't need a prefix in the source document. I just explained it, because you asked how it would look like and if it has to be the same as in the stylesheet.

Comment: You should try `<xsl:value-of select="../../aa:root_ID"/>` when 'aa' is the prefix.